# AJAX pagination requests growing exponentially

Tags: jquery, pagination

I have a window with some (jQuery ajax) tabs, in each one I show some information about the user: messages sent, received, posts made and comments made. I need to do some pagination which work well when going back and forth between pages. But in the last two tabs (posts and comments written) I see the requests done exponentially increase. Here is part of the code

```
if ($pageno != $lastpage) { 
   echo '<div class="item next_page" id="next_page_no_'.$nextpage.'">Siguiente</div>';
}
```

The code of the jQuery call working fine:

```
$(".display_messages").on("click", ".next_page", function(){
var pageno = $(this).attr('id').replace('next_page_no_','');
$.get('retrieve_messages_rec.php?pageno='+pageno,function(data) {
    $('.display_messages').html(data);
})
});
```

The code of the jQuery call working not that well:

```
$(".show_last_posts").on("click", ".next_page_posts", function(){
var pageno = $(this).attr('id').replace('next_page_no_','');
var usr_id= <?php echo mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['usr_id']); ?>;
$.get('user_last_posts.php?pageno='+pageno+'&usr_id='+usr_id,function(data) {
    $('.show_last_posts').html(data);
})
});
```

To give a better idea, when you click '.next_page' in the code working fine you see one request done each time you click. But when you click in '.next_page_posts' (in the second example) you get one request of the file 'user_last_posts.php' the very first time, three requests the second click (for next couple of posts), six requests to go to the third page, twelve for next, 24 then and so on. Why is it looping that way? Are the pieces of code shown here enough to see where my mistake is? Since they are basically identical, why it works fine in some of them but not in others? Or am I paranoid and that's normal? Thanks

Comment: Adding '$.one($.get...' calls the file twice only, but I am aiming to load it once only.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is between `.next_page_posts` and `.next_page`. `.next_page` is bound to a single element, while `.next_page_posts` is bound to each post. Compare the two selectors:

```
console.log( [".next_page_posts:",  $(".next_page_posts").length,  ".next_page:",  $(".next_page").length] )
```